# recursive function which will return number of binary ones from the given number

Tags: c, recursion

I have written recursive function which will return me the count of number of one bits from a given number. Whenever I try to run the code, it says segmentation fault core dump. Please tell me what’s going wrong in this code??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int no;
    printf("Enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    printf("Count of Number of One Bits is:%d\n",recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no));
    //recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no);   
}

int recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(int no){
int x=1;
int count=0;

    if((no&x)!=0)
    {
        count++;
        x=x<<1; 
    }
    return recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(count);

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `count` to the recursive call?

Comment: When does the recursion stop?  What's your terminating condition?  Isn't it when no is 0?

Comment: to return the count. Is it the way i supposed to call?? Or am i wrong??

Comment: Surely you are. You want the function to know the number you are counting the bits in. I would add an extra parameter to accumulate the count..

Comment: so what change should i supposed to do??

Comment: `x=x<<1;` is pointless as `x` is local to the function and always set to 1.

Comment: `F(number) = F(number >> 1) + isOdd(number)`. And a stop condition of course... (note, this is true for positive/unsigned numbers only)

Comment: Use your debugger or put some `printf`s at strategic points of your program and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it for unsigned integers.  Notice how it just returns `1 +` each time a bit is set, and continues to recurse as long as `no` is not zero.  Finally adding in a zero at the end.

```
int recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(unsigned int no)
{
    if (no&1)
        return 1 + recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no>>1);
    else if (no)
        return recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no>>1);
    else
        return 0;    
}
```

And a slightly golfier version

```
int recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(unsigned n) {
    return n?(n&1)+recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(n/2):0;    
}
```

Comment: The answer just gives the OP code that works without explaining what was wrong. Instead of answering conceptual questions, you have provided a code-writing service, allowing students to complete assignments without learning as much as they should.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I tried to explain how the code is working and what it should return each time it recurses along with how the recursion terminates.

Answer (score -1):

```
int recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(int no)
{
    if (no&1)
        return 1 + recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no>>1);
    else if (no)
        return recursiveCountNumberOfOnes(no>>1);
    else
        return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Please don't only post code,  add an explanation with it to make it clear for future visitors beginner and advanced alike